# nodemon not able to start nodejs app with express v4

Tags: node.js, express, npm, webstorm, nodemon

There must have some simple solution with this problem. I have created a new project using **Webstorm** for Express js + Node js. Then i installed **nodemon** using `npm install -g nodemon` and it was fine. But when i am trying to start my app using `nodemon app.js` it is showing only

> sany2k8@sany2k8-Aspire-4752:/var/projects/ENStack$ **nodemon app.js**
>
> [nodemon] 1.9.2
>
> [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon] watching: *.*
>
> [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
>
> [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ENStack",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

**Edit:** When i tried with `npm start` then it is showing bunch of errors

sany2k8@sany2k8-Aspire-4752:/var/projects/ENStack$ **npm start**

> ENStack@0.0.0 start /var/projects/ENStack
>   node ./bin/www

**Port 3000 is already in use**

Comment: I remember having same problem but long long ago, and it was related to [npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions). yours however dosen't seems to be so, but have you installed it with proper permission?

Comment: yes @AbhinavGauniyal

Comment: have you checked your processes to verify that it isn't running? No error messages?

Comment: is app.js working when you run `node app.js` ?

Comment: What are the errors your receive ? Port 3000 is already in use happens when you're running another node app in another process at port 3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we need to add **start** with **nodemon ./bin/www** in the **json** file and 
run your project using: `nodemon app`

```
{
  "name": "ENStack",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, some times, the port are in use. If the solution above not work for you, try change the port. It may be in use for some other node instance.